# How to word-wrap the column from material-ui DataGrid?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tailwind-css

i'm trying to word wrap my column header title of DataGrid from material-ui, but with no luck.

I've tried to use sx, style, but It doesn't work.
Tried this too:

```
const StyledDataGridtwo = styled(DataGrid)<DataGridProps>(({ theme }) => ({
root: {
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle': {
        wordWrap: 'break-word'
    }
}}))
<StyledDataGridtwo rows={rows} columns={columns} />
```

But it doesn't work. I want to make something like excel does.
There's any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main property that needs to be overridden is the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) CSS property (rather than the `word-wrap` property). However `line-height` also needs to be adjusted, otherwise it wraps in a very ugly way (56px per line of text). If you have the potential for your headers to wrap to more than 3 lines, then you also need to override some height CSS for the headers.

Here's a working example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const rows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: "@MUI",
    age: 20
  }
];

export default function HeaderColumnsGrid() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 250, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        sx={{
          "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": {
            whiteSpace: "normal",
            lineHeight: "normal"
          },
          "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader": {
            // Forced to use important since overriding inline styles
            height: "unset !important"
          },
          "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
            // Forced to use important since overriding inline styles
            maxHeight: "168px !important"
          }
        }}
        columns={[
          {
            field: "username",
            headerName: "Really long header name",
            description:
              "The identification used by the person with access to the online service."
          },
          { field: "age", headerName: "Another really long header name" }
        ]}
        rows={rows}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wrap headers]

I also recommend up-voting the issue that exists for this: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/898.

Comment: You were right in the spot! Thank you very much! Now I understand how to use sx and emotion engine to edit and make my custom components! Thank you very much! I've spent about 20 hours trying random stuff!

Comment: I used `sx` for convenience reasons, but the same styles should also work just fine using the `styled` api.

Comment: I just used this some in my own project and the `height` and `maxHeight` overrides do not behave well in some scenarios. Might be best to avoid needing more than the default 56px of header height.

Answer (score 0):

We need to set a headerName title row height change and disable filter/show&hide/column menu:

```
 headerHeight={30} 
 rowHeight={25}
 disableColumnFilter 
 disableColumnSelector 
 disableColumnMenu  
 disableSelectionOnClick
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this in a different way, for your data grid col config do:

```
const cols: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: "fieldA",
    width: 100,
    renderHeader: () => {
      return (
        <div style={{ lineHeight: "1.5em" }}>
          <span>LongWordA</span>
          <br />
          <span>LongWordB</span>
        </div>
      );
    },
  },
];
```

I also used disableColumnMenu: true and sortable: false if you don't need them.

You may also want to increase **columnHeaderHeight** in DataGrid component